# List View UpdateCommand passing nulls

Tags: listview

I am trying to get a `listview` to automatically bind and update data elements. After looking at numerous examples and tutorials, I still can't seem to find what is wrong with my code. The display is working just fine. It is just the update command that fails. Here is my `SqlDataSource` node:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MSSQLDataSource" runat="server"
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConn%>"
                   DataSourceMode="DataSet"
                   SelectCommand="select isnull(visits, 0) as Visits, iis.VirtualName, iis.clientname, iis.devurl, iis.stagingurl , iis.liveurl from iissites iis left join (select count(*) as visits, VirtualName from devvisits group by VirtualName) dv on iis.VirtualName = dv.VirtualName order by visits desc" UpdateCommand="update iissites set clientname = @clientname, stagingurl = @stagingurl where VirtualName = @VirtualName">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="clientname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="stagingurl" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="VirtualName" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Note that the `@VirtualName` parameter is being picked up (but not bound because it is the PK). Here is my `asp:ListView` node:

```
<asp:ListView DataSourceID="MSSQLDataSource" runat="server" DataKeyNames="VirtualName">            
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="1">
            <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th id="Th2">Clent Name</th>
                <th id="Th1">Local Site</th>
                <th id="Th3">LHits</th>
                <th>Staging</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="ItemPlaceHolder" runat="server" ></tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr runat="server" class='<%# Container.DataItemIndex % 2 == 0 ? "row" : "row alt" %>'>
           <td class="command"><asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="images/edit.jpg"  ID="btnEdit" runat="server"  Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" /></td>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("clientname") ?? "nbsp;" %>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnCommand="clickLink"
                                CommandName="devvisits" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("VirtualName") %>'
                                runat="server" ><%#Eval("VirtualName") ?? "nbsp;"%>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <%#Eval("Visits") ?? "nbsp;" %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("stagingurl") ?? "nbsp;" %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <EditItemTemplate>
        <tr id="TrEdit" runat="server">
            <td>
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="images/cancel.jpg" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="images/save.jpg" runat="server" ID="UpdateButton" CommandName="Update" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="clientname" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("clientname") %>'  ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:Label ID="VirtualName" runat="server">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" OnCommand="clickLink"
                                    CommandName="devvisits"
                                    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("VirtualName") %>'
                                    runat="server" ><%#Eval("VirtualName") %>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:Label ID="DevHits" runat="server">
                   <%#Eval("Visits") %>
                </asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("stagingurl") %>'  ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Any feedback would be appreciated.

-Jesse

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with it a lot too, found a workarond but it is really ugly.  I get the value from the controls in the ListView ItemUpdating event, store the values in local variables, then I handle the objectdatasource Updating event, set the properties of the object with these values.  I use the DataObjectTypeName of the objectdatasource.  Don't like that solution, but it's the only thing that worked for me and I can move on...